# Randomised Median

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms

I have tried hard , but i'm unable to come up with the expected running time for the number of comparisons to find the Randomized Median (find the median of an unsorted array). 
Also i wanted to make sure that we CANNOT take expectation of the recurrence that we use to find the randomized mean , or any other recurrence in any other problem as they belong to different probability spaces? Is this statement right?

Comment: Have you been shown a way of calculating the expected running time of randomized quicksort?

Comment: What is the algorithm your question relates to? Talking about runtime without a concrete algorithm does not make much sense, and particularities may matter. What is the recurrence you have at hand?

Comment: @Raphael sry for that. I basically take a random pivot and divide the array . If the pivot is at position n/2 i return if less , I select the right par and recursively find element of rank -(n/2-rank(pivot)) if greater i recurse on right and find recursively element of rank n/2

Comment: @Yuval Yes we have been

Comment: @Aditya In that case, try to mimic the argument you've seen.

Comment: @Yuval i tries so , but could come up with the proper indicator random variables and their associated probabilities

Comment: @AdityaNambiar: So this is Quickselect with random pivot. You should edit your question accordingly, include your attempt and explain where you are stuck. Then we can reopen the question.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to form up a recurrence for the *expected* running time $T(n)$. At each stage there is $O(n)$ processing, and the result is a new list of length distributed according to some distribution $D_n$ (for you to determine), and so we can write
$$ T(n) = O(n) + \operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{m \sim D_n} T(m). $$
This looks much less frightening when you substitute the actual distribution $D_n$ and replace the expectation with a (weighted) sum. Then it remains to solve the recurrence.

Comment: In quicksort it was pointed out that we could not take expectation over the recurrence relation since the probability space for T(n) is different from T(n-k) or T(k) {which were in the recurrence relation). Hence we did that indicator random variable and found probability 2/(j-i+1) and solved it. Doesnt the same apply here

Comment: If you partition with respect to the $k$th ranked pivot, then what you get on the left is a uniformly random permutation of the smallest $k-1$ elements, and what you get on the right is a uniformly random permutation of the largest $n-k$ elements. This is because the elements are put in the partitions in the order they are encountered in the array. So I don't see any problem with taking the expectation over the recurrence relation.

Comment: The indicator random variable trick is just a different way of tackling the problem. You can try to apply it here as well. If you're not successful, either try a little harder, or follow the other approach.

Comment: Hence the probability space for the left part would be all permutation of k elements and probabilities of right part all permutation of n-k elements which is  diff from earlier probability space. However expectation add only over same probability space.

Comment: It's only different if you are dogmatic about the contents of your array. For me, $T(n)$ is the expected running time on *any* array consisting of distinct elements, ordered uniformly at random.